# R - Conditional Replacements

Tags: r, replace, duplicates, conditional-statements, tibble

I want to replace values in a tibble when a condition is met.

```
Data <- tibble(a = 1:5,
b = c("a","b","a","a","a"), 
c = c("z","y","x","z","z"), 
d = c("m","n","m","m","m"),
e = c(1,3,4,7,2))

  a b c d e
1 1 a z m 1
2 2 b y n 3
3 3 a x m 4
4 4 a z m 7
5 5 a z m 2
```

I want to replace rows that contain duplicated combinations of columns b, c & d based on the greatest value in column a. Here rows 1, 4 and 5 all contain "a", "z" and "m" in columns b, c & d, so this example would output as follows:

```
  a b c d e
1 5 a z m 2
2 2 b y n 3
3 3 a x m 4
4 5 a z m 2
5 5 a z m 2
```

Comment: Sorry not sure what happened there, it appears I need some lessons in Stack Overflow.
Should make sense now.

Comment: See my answer edits, I think it's what you need now.

Comment: r2evans you absolute hero! You've solved a problem I've been working on and off for months so thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one thought, updated for the revised requirement that `e` is updated to the value of `e` from the row with the maximum `a`.

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(b,c,d) %>%
  mutate(e = e[which.max(a)], a = max(a)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#       a b     c     d         e
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     5 a     z     m         2
# 2     2 b     y     n         3
# 3     3 a     x     m         4
# 4     5 a     z     m         2
# 5     5 a     z     m         2
```

The order of calculating `e` and `a` is, of course, critical: if you `max(a)` first, then `e` won't know which *original* value of `a` was the max.

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
cols <- c("a", "e")
as.data.table(Data)[, c("e", "a") := .(e[which.max(a)], max(a)), by = .(b, c, d)][]
#    a b c d e
# 1: 5 a z m 2
# 2: 2 b y n 3
# 3: 3 a x m 4
# 4: 5 a z m 2
# 5: 5 a z m 2
```

(The trailing `[]` is just a minor feature/bug in `data.table` ... it is only required for aesthetics, the data is the same without it.)

Comment: Thank you, the tidyverse solution works, however what about cases where E column is not the max but rather a character?

Comment: (1) Technically, `max(LETTERS)` still works, so it won't error. (2) I really have no idea, I don't know the data and you never hinted that that was a possibility. It sounds like your sample data is not really representative of your actual data?

Comment: Yeah it's my first time submitting on StackOverflow so wasn't sure what I needed to include :) 
My issue is that row 5 is actually 5 a z m 5
and so I would want rows 1 and 4 to reflect that given that row 5 has the greatest value in column a.
Again sorry if this isn't clear, it's my first time

Comment: I don't understand how the code I suggested does not work, even with that change. I suggest you edit your question to update the data to be *that*, and be sure to update your expected output as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) hopefully the edit will make it clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `ave`

```
Data$a <- with(Data, ave(a, b, c, d, FUN = max))
Data$e <- with(Data, ave(e, b, c, d, FUN = max))
```